# Can a Corda node initiate a flow session with itself?

Tags: corda

In a Corda flow, you can initiate a `FlowSession` with a counterparty to send and receive data.

Can a node initiate a `FlowSession` with themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is completely fine. For example, the following would work:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val selfSession = initiateFlow(ourIdentity)
        selfSession.send("It's me!")
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        logger.info(counterpartySession.receive<String>().unwrap { it })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Corda 4 this will throw an exception with message:

> Do not provide flow sessions for the local node. FinalityFlow will record the notarised transaction locally.